# Google ignoring Canonical tag

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, rel-canonical

I have two pages on the site that are 100% identical:

MyDomain.com
MyDomain.com/Keyword

MyDomain.com/Keyword exists solely because I had to give the page I created in the CMS a url, and that page is then also displayed as the home page.

Recently Google started displaying MyDomain.com/Keyword in the serps for "Keyword" searches instead of the homepage. That (I believe) caused the site to drop several places in the serps since the March 2019 update.

both pages contain a canonical tag informing google that the home page is to be treated as the source, but for some reason Google has decided (after many years) to ignore this.

Has anyone experienced such behavior from Google? What did you do?

Should I do a 301 from MyDomain.com/Keyword to MyDomain.com?

Answer (score 2):

yes you should make this redirection.

Meta canonical isn't enough in that case because it won't prevent your page to be indexed by Google.

Canonical are used for pages that aimed to be indexed without hurting canonical url seo.

Answer (score 0):

A canonical is one of the signals that Google uses to decides which page to index and show on the SERPs; because of that, they can decide to ignore it if the other signals point to another page that appears to be a better match.

The signals they use for this:

- Link rel canonical annotation that matches throughout the site
- Redirects
- Internal linking using the preferred URL format
- Preferred URLs in the sitemap file

*[Source](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/googles-john-mueller-explains-how-canonical-urls-are-chosen/324371/)*